# replace characters in a string using an associative array mapping

Tags: javascript, replace, associative-array

I have an associative array/object such at this:

```
mymap = {'e':'f', 'l':'g'};
```

And I want to replace all matching characters in a string using the above as a simple cypher, but only replacing existing characters. As an example,

```
input = "hello world";
output = input.map(mymap); //how can I do this?
//output is "hfggo worgd"
```

Balancing performance (for large input) and code size are of interest.

---

My application is replacing unicode characters with latex strings using [this map](https://gist.github.com/yourcelf/6055894), but I'm happy to stick with the more general question.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
mymap = {'e':'f', 'l':'g'};

var replacechars = function(c){
    return mymap[c] || c;
};

input = "hello world";
output = input.split('').map(replacechars).join('');
```

although having to split and then join the input seems quite round-about, particularly if this is applied to a wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be loop over the object properties and use regex for each replacement:

```
var input = 'hello world';
var output = '';

for (var prop in mymap) {
    if (mymap.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var re = new RegExp(prop, 'g');
        output = input.replace(re, mymap[prop]);
    }
}
```